# Laravel query relationship issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to check if inside a relationships there is a given value but i got an error when i try to fetch the variable i need inside the loop. I get  "message": "Undefined variable: cat".
Here is my code

```
$cate = $request->input('category');
                foreach ($cate as $key => $cat) {
                    $restaurants->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('name', '==', $cat);
                    }]);
                }
```

can someone help me figure out?

Answer (score 0):

you must use "whereHas" instead of "with" to check if relationship have pass condition:

```
$cate = $request->input('category');
foreach ($cate as $key => $cat) {
    $restaurants->whereHas(['categories', function ($query) use ($cat) {
       $query->where('name', '==', $cat);
    }]);
}
```

and for your questions: import variable to the current scope (the use keyword)

Answer (score 0):

what is inside your `$cate` variable ?

and what do you want to do ?

If you want to search your Restaurants matching your given categories in your input, then you should do this :

```
// assuming your $request->input('category') look like this :

$categories = ['foo', 'bar'];

$restaurants = Restaurant::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($categories){
    $query->whereIn('name', $categories);
})->get();
```

(just for explaining your error, you have to pass you $cat variable to your closure :

```
$restaurants->with(['categories' => function ($query) use ($cat) {
                    $query->where('name', '==', $cat);
                    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to just pass the $cat variable to your closure => **function ($query) use ($cat)**

```
$cate = $request->input('category');
            foreach ($cate as $key => $cat) {
                $restaurants->whereHas(['categories' => function ($query) use ($cat) {
                $query->where('name', $cat);
                }]);
            }
```

use whereHas() to specify additional filters in the relationship.

Show More => https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships